# Is is possible to update Qml Android application by changing qml file remotely

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtandroidextras, qqmlapplicationengine

I am wondering if it is possible to update qml android application remotely by changing qml file. To do this :

Qml should be read from the filesystem of the device dynamically instead embedding into the apk.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use a `Loader` to load files with any URL. You might change that URL if there is a new version. To bypass the cache you might add the timestamp to the filename. Then you only need a watch dog that will trigger a signal if a new file appears in the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you will only embed a small loader, possibly including an updater into the APK, which can load a QML file from the device filesystem.

On startup you can check for a new version, if available download and save it and only then load the QML file.

Note that for any non-trivial application you will most likely need [to define external files as an external module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-identifiedmodules.html) so you can have your custom external types resolve properly.